# Convert long to two int and vice versa

Tags: java, int, long-integer

How can I convert two 32 bit integers (`int`) to one 64 bit `long` and vice versa?

Comment: In what way to you want to convert them? One possibility: (a << Integer.SIZE) | b

Comment: Signed or unsigned?  If unsigned, then what would negative values mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java storing two ints in a long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772939/java-storing-two-ints-in-a-long)

Answer (score 51):

```
long c = (long)a << 32 | b & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
int aBack = (int)(c >> 32);
int bBack = (int)c;
```

In Java, you don't need quite so many parentheses, or any masking on the reverse calculation.

Comment: Lessee:  `for (long i = Long.MIN_VALUE; i <= Long.MAX_VALUE; i++) {...`

Comment: 292 years is far far less than it will take. My computer also claims 292 years, as will everyone elses. For me `(stop - start)*2.0/reps*Long.MAX_VALUE)`is 1.207154932183553E22 while Long.MaxValue is 9223372036854775807 so when the cast to `(long)` happens everyone ends up with 9223372036854775807. As thats 1/1308th the true value the time should actually be 382,000 years. (Still +1 though since the actual answer is correct)

Comment: Haha, very nice Richard. I'm in the habit of never doing the millis-to-something-else conversion manually, but I also rarely try to get millisecond resolution on hundreds (or hundreds of thousands) of years. As I am no longer a teacher, I'll just edit out the whole "exercise" bit. The answer doesn't need to be so long.

Comment: Sorry if this is clear to everyone. Can someone explain this please. I understand the first part that we are vacating the last 32 bits. What is the second part doing. What will AND with all 1's give? I tried this with ((long)a << 32) + b and it gives the same out put and thats why I am wondering what the mask is in place for.

Comment: (long)a << 32 + b only works when b is positive. In Java, ints are signed, so you have to appropriately deal with the sign. We aren't ANDing with all 1's, the mask is a long (64 bits) with the lower 32 bits as 1's, this effectively treats b as an unsigned int when we are storing it in a long.

Answer (score 2):

Ints to longs:

```
long c = ((long)a << 32) | ((long)b & 0xFFFFFFFFL);
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to perform the reverse calculation.  But the hint is; use more bit-shifts and [bit-masks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_mask).

(Edited as per comment by T. Murdock)

Comment: I think b is may well already be assumed to be valid, given the circumstances.

Comment: This answer is subtly wrong: it will fail for `b = 0x1FFFFFFF`, on account of containing (as of this comment) seven Fs in the mask, not eight. That means it fails not only for all negative values of b (as the answer with no mask would fail), but also for large positive values of b.