# Java storing two ints in a long

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, primitive

I want to store two ints in a long (instead of having to create a new `Point` object every time).

Currently, I tried this. It's not working, but I don't know what is wrong with it:

```
// x and y are ints
long l = x;
l = (l << 32) | y;
```

And I'm getting the int values like so:

```
x = (int) l >> 32;
y = (int) l & 0xffffffff;
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`y` is getting sign-extended in the first snippet, which would overwrite `x` with `-1` whenever `y < 0`.

In the second snippet, the cast to `int` is done before the shift, so `x` actually gets the value of `y`.

```
long l = (((long)x) << 32) | (y & 0xffffffffL);
int x = (int)(l >> 32);
int y = (int)l;
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. One question I have is whether it matters if you bitmask using the long 0xffffffffL or the int 0xffffffff.

Comment: @LanguagesNamedAfterCofee yes it matters, if you mask with `0xffffffff` (without the L) then it's just an int, so the `&` is a no-op and `y` *still gets sign extended*.

Answer (score 14):

Here is another option which uses a bytebuffer instead of bitwise operators. Speed-wise, it is slower, about 1/5 the speed, but it is much easier to see what is happening:

```
long l = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putInt(x).putInt(y).getLong(0);
//
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(l);
x = buffer.getInt(0);
y = buffer.getInt(4);
```

Comment: Java 8 has `Long.BYTES`, even more clear than the magic number 8.

Comment: `y = buffer.getInt(4);` - the argument is the byte offset, so it's 4.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to store two Float values that are (32-bits) as a single Long value (64-bits). You can convert the bits from the float value into bits for integer value and then to the same as the previous answers.

```
// first method using floatToIntBits 
long method1(float x, float y) {

    int xInt = java.lang.Float.floatToIntBits(x);
    int yInt = java.lang.Float.floatToIntBits(y);
    
    return (((long)xInt) << 32) | (yInt & 0xffffffffL);
}

// second method using ByteBuffer
long method2(float x, float y) {
    return ByteBuffer.allocate(java.lang.Long.BYTES).putFloat(x).putFloat(y).getLong(0);
}
```