# Storing two ints in a long

Tags: javascript, binary, bit-shift

This question is a extension to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772939/java-storing-two-ints-in-a-long). Is it possible to store two integers in a long in JavaScript?

```
long l = (((long)x) << 32) | (y & 0xffffffffL);
int x = (int)(l >> 32);
int y = (int)l;
```

Comment: Did you try and what are your results?

Comment: all numbers in JavaScript are floating point.

Comment: why would you want to do this ? is it not easier to create an object? `l = {x:x, y:y}`

Comment: temp = (10 << 32) | (15 & 0xffffffffL) SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL, e.g.

Comment: JavaScript can only represent integers up to 2^53 precisely. And if you use bitwise operators, the operands are actually converted to 32bit ints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's JavaScript, not java. Here you got only floating point numbers. I don't see any point in such operation, but you could return a tuple, or make a string out of them with a separator. But keeping them inside one number...

But in JS you have also shifting operator, so you could try this one:D

Comment: I didn't know about the floating point stuff. Thanks anyway :)