# How to read Long (Swapped) value from Modbus?

Tags: java, modbus

I need to read Long (swapped) value from Modbus register.

[image]

From picture above I want to read register 42002 which has value of 78146789. This is in Long (Swapped ) format. It looks like this in Decimal format:

[image]

I am using Java shorts array to read this. I am getting 1192,27877 correctly. Now I need to convert these values to proper value which is 78146789 in this case. How to do this? How is Long (Swapped) represented here ?

Comment: can you show us your code please?

Comment: @YCF_L It is simply a call to a Modbus library available in market. The call looks like this: readMultipleRegisters(intSlaveAddress, intStartRef%40000, (short[]) objRead); here objRead is a short array I am passing in which I get the values.

Comment: You mentioned you are trying to read the value in register 42002 but then you go on to say that the proper value you want is 78146789, which is really spread across register 42002 and 42003.  So are you really trying to read the value in 42002 or the value in 42002 & 42003 (as one number)?

Comment: @JoseMartinez 42002 & 42003 form a number.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772939/java-storing-two-ints-in-a-long . Use shorts and ints instead of ints and long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ByteBuffer to convert the shorts to a long.  But you have to add the leading 0's

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    short x = 1192;
    short y = 27877;
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
    bb.clear();
    bb.putShort((short) 0);
    bb.putShort((short) 0);
    bb.putShort(x);
    bb.putShort(y);
    bb.flip();
    System.out.println("" + bb.getLong());
}
```