# ModbusTcpClient: How to read long integer values from Input registers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, modbus, modbus-tcp

I am trying to get data from a sensor using ModbusTcpClient as below

```
client = ModbusTcpClient('xx.xx.xx.xx', port=502)
connection = client.connect()
request = client.read_input_registers(220,2, unit=51, debug=False)
result = request.registers
print(result)
```

With this result i am getting a list of **unsigned decimal**. How can i convert this to **long int** or **swapped long**

The result i am getting from the above code

```
2023-04-24 12:18:59,856 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :297      RECV: 0x0 0x2 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x7 0x33 0x4 0x4 0x0 0x28 0x8a 0x23
2023-04-24 12:18:59,857 MainThread      DEBUG    socket_framer  :147      Processing: 0x0 0x2 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x7 0x33 0x4 0x4 0x0 0x28 0x8a 0x23
2023-04-24 12:18:59,857 MainThread      DEBUG    factory        :266      Factory Response[ReadInputRegistersResponse: 4]
2023-04-24 12:18:59,858 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :454      Adding transaction 2
2023-04-24 12:18:59,859 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :465      Getting transaction 2
2023-04-24 12:18:59,859 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :224      Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'
[40, 35363]
```

But i need the **[40, 35363]** to be shown as **swapped long** as **2656849**

Thanks,

**Edit:**

I have answered with my code below

Comment: Are you sure that 2656849 is what you want and not 2656803 ? Also, have you seen this:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48599148/how-to-read-long-swapped-value-from-modbus

Comment: @DarkKnight, thank you for replying. Is there a way to do this in python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i achieved this by the following code,

```
client = ModbusTcpClient('xx.xx.xx.xx', port=502)
connection = client.connect()
request = client.read_input_registers(220,2, unit=51, debug=False)
result = request.registers

decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(request.registers, byteorder=Endian.Big, wordorder=Endian.Big)
active_power_w = decoder.decode_32bit_int()
print(active_power_w)
```

Hope this helps...!

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments I'd expect the result to be `2656803` ([this calculator](https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/) is useful for checking possible encodings).

There are a few options; [unpack](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) is frequently used:

```
import struct
print(struct.unpack('>i', bytes.fromhex("00288a23")))
```

Alternatively pymodbustcp provides some [utilities](https://pymodbustcp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/package/module_utils.html#pyModbusTCP.utils.word_list_to_long) that can help (see [this example](https://pymodbustcp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/client_float.html#client-add-float-inheritance)). This enables you to do something like this:

```
reg = client.read_input_registers(220,2, unit=51, debug=False)
print(word_list_to_long(reg)[0])
```

*Please note that I have not tested the above code*.